# Как узнать, сколько памяти использует программа? (Java)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Есть код программы-калькулятора, надо узнать сколько памяти он использует при запуске.
Видела такой ответ:

```
long usedBytes = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

Но что это и куда это, не представляю.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если при запуске, то можно сравнить разницу памяти вот так:

```
public class Calculator {
     public static long mem() {
         Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
         return runtime.totalMemory() - runtime.freeMemory();
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         long before = mem();
         // какие-то действия
         long after = mem();
         System.out.println("Diff " + (after - before));
     }
}
```