# Как оценить эффективность моего алгоритма?

Tags: java

Изучаю Java, решаю задачи. Для одной задачи возможно несколько вариантов решения. Подскажите, как оценить эффективность моего алгоритма? Единственное, что я придумал - оценка затраченного времени и вывод его в консоль:

```
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    //какой-то код
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
```

Возможно, как-то можно еще оценить эффективность алгоритма (например, потребление памяти)? И нужно ли? И на что еще обращать внимание при написании алгоритмов?

Comment: Ну... в начале любой книги и курса по алгоритмам описывается понятие алгоритмической сложности, по времени и по памяти. Хотя бы общее понятие об этом стоит приобрести.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильное измерение скорости выполнения кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/947914/); [Как узнать, сколько памяти использует программа? (Java)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/592436/)

Comment: Затраченное время на выполнение какого-то кода и эффективность алгоритма в этом коде связаны довольно слабо. Если в код добавить вывод информации, то время увеличится, и иногда значительно, хотя алгоритм при этом совсем не изменится. Точно так же затраченное время не очень подходит для сравнения разных алгоритмов. Алгоритм может быть более эффективным, но не очень удачно переведен в код, и поэтому код будет выполнятся медленнее.

Comment: @Эникейщик Кроме того на разных данных (разного размера и состава) алгоритмы могут себя вести по-разному. Бывает, что алгоритм `O(n)` на данных небольшого размера работает медленнее, чем алгоритм `O(n^2)`, преимущество первого алгоритма проявляется только на данных достаточно большого размера )

Comment: Еще: вы упомянули оценку употребления памяти. Эффективность по времени (чем быстрее, тем лучше) и эффективность по памяти (чем меньше требуется, тем лучше) - это РАЗНЫЕ эффективности. Из одной совсем не следует другая, а чаще даже наоборот.  Поэтому при оценке эффективности нужно сначала решить, какую эффективность оцениваем. _Это как с автомобилями (пардон за заезженные аналогии): что эффективнее - феррари или камаз? А смотря для чего. Феррари едет быстрее, зато на камазе можно увезти 10 тонн._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сформулируйте задачу, которую решаете и алгоритм, который хочется оценить, так будет понятнее, что можно порекомендовать.
Небольшое замечание по поводу приведенного вами кода для оценки времени выполнения алгоритма. Перед замерами лучше делать "прогрев". Например, если оценивается время выполнения сортировки, то перед основным замером - прогоните сортировку несколько раз, а только потом замеряйте время выполнения алгоритма.
Рекомендую почитать: Эванс, Гоф, Ньюланд: Java. Оптимизация программ.